# Добавление строк в массив

Tags: java, arraylist

Вопрос по Java. Вроде простая задача, но не могу решить. Есть несколько строк

```
String str1 = "ABC";
String str2 = "DEF";
String str3 = "XYZ";
```

Нужно собрать ArrayList. Понятно, в идеале должно быть:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
array.add("ABC");
array.add("DEF");
array.add("XYZ");
```

Но все дело в том, что строк может быть от 2 до 32. И напрямую

```
array.add("XYZ");
```

не подходит. Подскажите как это сделать циклом. Или есть еще какие-либо приемы добавления. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Что значит "строк может быть от 2 до 32 и add не подходит"? Почему не подходит? Откуда вы берете строки?

Comment: Я пишу приложение под android. В приложении есть настройки, с помощью которых пользователь может выбирать, какой из новостных каналов он хочет отслеживать. Всего 32 канала. К примеру, он выбрал Россия24, BBC, 1канал. В данном случае 3 элемента добавляются (3 раза по array.add). Вот эти значения и нужно разместить в массиве. Эта выборка через запятую добавляется в запрос на сервер. (https://.........rus24,bbc,1can.json

Comment: А список каналов вы получаете откуда?

Comment: Есть самописное API, в котором работают парсеры, отслеживающие новостные сайты. Это был заказ и мобильное приложение делается как тестовое задание

Comment: Раз есть API, значит они приходят списками, и ваш вопрос теряет смысл. Показать пользователю полученный с сервера список и позволить выбрать из них несколько не вызвало бы у вас такого вопроса. Если это тестовое задание, то вынужден вас расстроить - вам не стоит браться за эту работу...

Comment: В том то и дело, что список с сервера на приходит. Приходят только те каналы, которые пользователь выбрал из листа на экране. Если он ничего не выбрал, приходят все 32 канала. Такое вот API.

Comment: Все еще не состыкуется с текстом вопроса...

Comment: Ваш пример в коде очень непонятен. Нажмите на кнопку «править» под вопросом, чтобы добавить все нужные детали. Предлагаю объяснить ситуацию с самого начала: какое у Вас приложение, как хранится список каналов в приложении, как из него выбираются значения, куда его нужно передать?

Answer (score 1):

```
array = ...
String s = "String";
int MAX = 100500;

for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    array.add(s + String.valueOf( i+1 ));
}
```

Вот [тут](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/initialize-an-arraylist-in-java/) написано (с примерами) про инициализацию ArrayList

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но у меня немного другая проблема. Я просто некорректно вопрос задал. Вопрос переписал.

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum ListString {

    String1, String2, String3  //Здесь перечисляете любое количество стрингов

}



import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ListString stringEnum : ListString.values()) {
            array.add(String.valueOf(stringEnum));
        }

        System.out.println(array);

    }
}
```